# Isn't this [A-Za-z] character class redundant here?

Tags: regex

I have this regex, `^[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z\.\@\-]{7,59}$`, but it seems to me that the first character class `[A-Za-z]` is completely redundant. Is that correct?

Comment: OK, smart ones, so far so good. But indeed, all of you that have answered, must admit that it is mildly wet to repeat `[A-Za-z]` twice. How to do it to only mention it once?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I'm not sure I follow what you mean but `^[A-Za-z]` is a separate requirement to `[0-9A-Za-z\.\@\-]{7,59}` so they cannot be combined...

Comment: @BorisStitnicky, I'm not sure that you can, and I'm okay with it being there if it's fulfilling that part of the overall requirements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No because that is insisting that the string starts with alpha (and ASCII alpha at that)

`^` is the start-anchor, so this string must start with alpha - then you may have any of the chars specified by the second character class.

And if you are using this regex to validate a string (some kind of variable name?) then you may also need the end-anchor `$`. Otherwise it will not care what *follows* the match...

```
^[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z\.\@\-]{7,59}$
```

This means that the string must be no more than 60 characters in total (including the leading alpha).

Comment: Yea, missed that trailing `$` on the copy. They already have it there. Fantastic answer friend!

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Haha ok, all is well! :)

Answer (score 3):

no, because `^[A-Za-z]` means it has to begin with a letter (caps or not). Without it, it could begin with a letter or a number or anything matching  `[0-9A-Za-z\.\@\-]`